# I tried Installing Arista vEOS in VirtualBox and i got this error: "No startup-configuration was found"

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, bios

the device is in zero touch provisioning mode and it is attempting to download the startup-configuration from a remote system.the device will not be fully functional until either a valid startup-config is downloaded from the remote system or zerotouch provisioning is cancelled

to cancel zerotouch provisioning, login as admin and type 'zerotouch cancel' at the CLI. Alternatively to disable zerotouch provisioning permanently type 'zerotouch disable' at the CLI.
note: the devise will reload when these commands are issued

was the error showing on my terminal...

Comment: sounds like normal Arista behavior--what is the question?